# Anyway to @Inject/@Autowire an inner class into an outer class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In Spring/JSR-330, is there a way to properly declare an inner class which requires dependency injection, such that I can inject it into the outer class?

For example:

```
@Component
public class TestClass{

    // How to declare this class?
    private class TestClassInner{
       @Autowired private SomeBean somebean;

       public boolean doSomeWork(){
          return somebean.doSomething();
       }               
    }

    // Inject the inner class here in the outer class such that the outer class can use an instance of it
    @Autowired TestClassInner innerClass;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ...
    }

    public void someMethod(){
       innerClass.doSomeWork();
       ...
    }
}
```

I've tried annotating the inner class with @Component, making it a public class, making it public static, etc, but it seems that every combination I've tried always ends up throwing one error or another.

As a private inner class, Spring complains that it is missing a constructor, even if I define one.

As an annotated `@Component` public static class, Spring complains that it find two beans - TestClass@TestClassInner and testClass.TestClassInner.  And if I use a `@Qualifier`, it then complains that the bean cannot be found.

I presume I am misunderstanding how these inner beans work/interact with Spring to properly understand if/how to declare them.

Is this even possible?

**Edit**

So here are a few combinations I've tried (including tried implementing a new constructor based on @SotiriosDelimanolis response):

```
    // How to declare this class?
@Component
public class TestClassInner{
    @Autowired private ProviderService providerService;

    public TestClassInner(){
        super();
    }
    public TestClassInner( TestClass t){
        super();
    }
}
```

Throws error (both public and private inner class throw the same error):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ia.exception.TestClass$TestClassInner]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ia.exception.TestClass$TestClassInner.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    ... 54 more
```

I just tried using a static public nested class with my test class (above) and it seems to inject properly.  On the other hand, in my actual controller, it discovers 2 matching classes:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ia.web.ContractController$InnerClass] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: com.ia.web.ContractController$InnerClass,contractController.InnerClass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:865)
```

**Edit 2**

```
@Controller
public class ContractController {

    @Component
    static public class InnerClass extends AttachmentControllerSupport{

        /**
         * 
         */
        public InnerClass() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public InnerClass( ContractController c){
            super();
        }
    }

    @Autowired private InnerClass innerclass;

    @Autowired private AttachmentControllerSupport attachmentControllerSupport;
    @Autowired private ContractService contractService;

}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ia">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
<context:spring-configured/>
```

restmvc-config.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService" >
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver" />
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: For starters, your incorrect terminology is confusing an issue that's complicated enough on its own. In Java, an "inner class" is specifically a non-static nested class; a nested class may be either inner or static.

Comment: @chrylis I actually didn't realize that.  Thanks for the clarification.  I've used the term "inner class" here to refer to the nested class.  I'll try to edit the post with that in mind

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible to declare and instantiate inner class beans through `@Component` annotations, but solution is ugly, but I will get to it later. First, here's how you can do it with `<bean>` declarations in XML. Given

```
package com.example;

public class Example {
    @Autowired
    private Inner inner;
    public class Inner {        
    }
}
```

you'd have

```
<bean name="ex" class="com.example.Example" />
<bean name="inner" class="com.example.Example$Inner">
    <constructor-arg ref="ex"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

For inner classes, any constructor implicitly declares its first parameter as an instance of the enclosing type.

So

```
public Inner() {}
```

above would actually be compiled to

```
public Inner (Example enclosingInstance) {}
```

With Java code, the argument for that parameter is implicitly provided with the syntax

```
enclosingInstance.new Inner();
```

Spring uses reflection to instantiate your bean classes and initialize your beans. And the concept described here also applies to reflection. The `Constructor` used to initialize the `Inner` class has to have its first parameter be of the type of the enclosing class. That's what we are doing explicitly here by declaring a `constructor-arg`.

The solution for using `@Component` depends on a few things. First, you have to know all the things discussed above. Basically, with a `Constructor` object, when you call `newInstance()`, you need to pass an instance of the enclosing class as the first argument. Second, you have to know how Spring processes the annotation. When the annotated class has a single constructor annotated with `@Autowired`, that's the constructor it will choose to initialize the bean. It also uses the `ApplicationContext` to resolve beans to inject as arguments to the constructor.

Playing on those two facts, you can write a class like this

```
@Component
public class Example {
    @Component
    public class Inner {
        @Autowired
        public Inner() {}

    }
}
```

Here, our inner class has an `@Autowired` constructor, so Spring knows exactly which `Constructor` object to use. Because of the `@Autowired` it will also try to find a bean from the `ApplicationContext` to match and inject for every parameter the constructor has. In this case, the only parameter is of type `Example`, the enclosing class. Since `Example` is also annotated with `@Component`, it's also a bean in the context, so Spring can inject it into the constructor of the inner class.