# Initialize beans in inner Static test class in springBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit-runner

I am using nested classes for writing unit test cases in spring boot. My test case file is :

```
@RunWith(NestedRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class OuterTestCase {

        public static class InnerTestCases {

             @Autowired
             private RestTemplate restTemplate;
             @Autowired
             private MockMvc mockMvc;

             @Test
             public void testcase(){
              //do Something
             }
        }
}
```

But I am getting NPE when tried using **RestTemplate** inside testCase method.

I am unable to initialize beans inside the inner class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Autowired not working in inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720329/autowired-not-working-in-inner-class)

Comment: Basically have to annotate the inner static class as some sort of bean - perhaps @Component. Otherwise you have to manage the dependencies yourself.

Comment: adding component bean also doesn't work. @RandyCasburn

And also I checked the above link but that too didn't answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

A static class gets initialized during early stages of class loading. Unless the Autowired class has been initialized using a static class you will encounter above error.