# Create beans from inner class using spring

Tags: spring

I was trying to define a class something below. Spring is not instantiating the beans.

```
    @Component
    public class A{
        @Component
        public class B{
         }
     }
```

Is there any way to let Spring create beans like above.

Comment: Does the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24213978/2809078) help? The constructor of the inner class needs an instance of the outer class, so it needs to be marked as `@Autowired`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyway to @Inject/@Autowire an inner class into an outer class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213823/anyway-to-inject-autowire-an-inner-class-into-an-outer-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so because the inner class **can not** exist without its enclosing class. therefore it **can** only be injected into the enclosing Bean.

[From Spring documentations:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-inner-beans)

> An inner bean definition does not require a defined id or name; the container ignores these values. It also ignores the scope flag. Inner beans are always anonymous and they are always created with the outer bean. It is not possible to inject inner beans into collaborating beans other than into the enclosing bean.

I think it is only possible only for `static` inner classes and not for `not-static inner` classes.

This should work:

```
    @Component
    public class A{
        @Component
        public static class B{
         }
     }
```