# Inner static class not picked by @Autowired in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-test

i have a inner static class like below

```
@component
public class test{
      @Autowired
      LocationRegistry locReg;

     @Component
    public static class LocationRegistry
    {
        private final ConcurrentMap<String, Path> locationPerRequest = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        ConcurrentMap<String, Path> getLocationPerRequest()
        {
            return locationPerRequest;
        }
    }

}
```

this gives an error
**Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'locationRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**

it was working fine with springboot 1.5.x version, when i moved to 2.4.3 it is failing with above error.

Sharing full stack details,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.recommind.AgreementCodeBasedFieldsAutoTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'locationRegistry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.xxxBasedFieldsAutoTest$LocationRegistry' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at com.xxx.DatabaseCreatingListener.injectDependencies(DatabaseCreatingListener.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:61)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:366)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:320)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
```

Kindly let me know what could be the reason...!

Comment: Can you post full stack trace?

Comment: @Jayesh, Added the full stack trace to the post.!

Comment: Have you considered filing an issue with spring framework? It sound like a regression.

Comment: as of now, not raised any query. Just wanted to clarify and correct my code just in case any.

Comment: @Vijay, are you OK with using `@Configuration` instead of `@Component` in LocationRegistry ?

Comment: Hmm.., I dont think so it helps, tried not worked @Jayesh

Comment: Have you looked at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213823/anyway-to-inject-autowire-an-inner-class-into-an-outer-class

Comment: yeah, of course @Jayesh. But my requirement here to make a static inner class.!