# spring boot - autowire and constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, constructor, autowired

Im not sure about approach to initialize and implement specific part of spring boot app.

I got e-commerce app that got Purchase class with fields (not sure whether its called field- eg "private String name;") and getters and setters. one of the field is shippingAddress address - own class with constructor with its fields.

My question is could I use:

```
Purchase purchase = context.getBean(Purchase.class);
purchase.setName("foo0");
purchase.setShippingAddress(new ShippingAddress("foo1", "foo2", "foo3"))
```

?(check last line). I mean, is going via "new" good approach? @Autowired annotation keeps popping into my mind but I think its not suitable here?

Comment: question has already been addressed in this forum.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213823/anyway-to-inject-autowire-an-inner-class-into-an-outer-class

Answer (score 0):

The `ShippingAddress` should be set for each user from input, not injected on startup by Spring.  `new` is appropriate here; `@Autowired` is not.