# How to use spring prototype scope for constructor arguments in case of interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interface, prototype

I have a legacy code, which I need to migrate using spring, and I have found one case like below

```
@Component // have to mark this as component
class ABC
{
  private static final class innerClass implements InterfaceClass
   {
     private String str;
     innerClass(String str){this.str = str};
     //some DAO methods..
     private Dao1 dao1;
     private Dao2 dao2;
   }
   private InterfaceClass intfClass;
   void getInnerClass(){
   if(intfClass == null || !(str.isEmpty())){
    intfClass = new innerClass (str);
    }
   }
}

public interface InterfaceClass{
... some methods declared..
}
```

Now the inner class innerClass contains some DAO's which i need to autowire and class ABC is marked as @Component so hence i dont think so we can keep the inner class as @Component here?
The scope of the inner class needs to be a prototype.

So to implement it,

I tried one factory implementation, in which I commented on the inner class and made it as a separate class, refer below

```
class innerClass {  //inner class which I made as a separate class
private String str;
innerClass(String str){this.str = str}
     private Dao1 dao1;
     private Dao2 dao2;
}

public interface InterfaceClass{
... some methods declared..
}

@Configuration
class innerClassFactory
{
@Autowire Dao1 dao1;
@Autowire Dao2 dao2;

@Bean
@Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public InterfaceClass getInnerClassObj(String str){
return new innerClass(str);
}
}

@Compoenent
class ABC{
@Autowire innerClassFactory;
private InterfaceClass intfClass;
   void getInnerClass(){
   if(innerClassFactory == null || !(str.isEmpty())){
    intfClass = getInnerClassObj (str);
    }
   }


}
```

After trying this still, the dao's are null, they aren't autowired
Also, the String str is populated earlier only,

Please suggest me any other option if possible.

Comment: In the factory you are creating the instance so spring not aware of this. return new innerClass(str);

Comment: Then what should i do ?

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213823/anyway-to-inject-autowire-an-inner-class-into-an-outer-class

Comment: Now working? If yes share the code...